# Reason Why 1 Coulomb was redefined in SI unit system?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, charge, si-units

Since current can be calculated as $I = q/t$, the original definition of 1 Coulomb in SI unit system was that it is such amount of charge which flows through wire cross-section having current of $1 A$  in $1 s$ of duration, i.e. $$\tag 1 1C=1A\cdot 1s$$.

Now it is [simply stated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb) that $1 C \approx 6~241~509~074~460~762~607.776~e$ (or exact scientific notation).

Now here comes my question,- Why definition of SI unit of charge was moved from that one related to current strength ?
Can it be because time is not Lorentz invariant under inertial reference frame,- i.e. time flow depends on what observer you choose as a reference frame (because it depends on object speed), hence different observers can measure different charge amount(s) flowing in same wires as per (1),- because 1 second unit is there. Hence (1) definition is **faulty** because charge is absolute quantity and cannot depend on a reference frame. Is that correct or there are other reasons why $1C$ original mapping was abandoned ?

From wiki:

> The SI defines the coulomb by taking the value of the elementary charge e to be $1.602176634×10^{−19} C$, but was previously defined in terms of the force between two wires

Comment: Read the actual [standard](https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/41483022/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf/2d2b50bf-f2b4-9661-f402-5f9d66e4b507?version=1.12&t=1685993350255&download=true). The Coulomb is still a derived unit and is still defined as one ampere-second. The definition of the ampere is what changed. There is **nothing faulty** about (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why definition of SI unit of charge was moved from that one related to current strength ?

Because the new standard is more accurate and stable than the previous standard.

> Can it be because time is not Lorentz invariant under inertial reference frame, … Hence (1) definition is faulty because charge is absolute quantity and cannot depend on a reference frame.

No. There was nothing faulty about the previous standard. This one is just more accurate and stable.

Comment: That is drift speed of charges depends only on local charge movement relative to the wires, and so it does not depend of wire movement itself as perceived from different observers and hence $1~A$ current in some wires will be measured the same in a stationary observer and that one which moves relative to the wires ? I.e. does ampere (current) - Lorentz invariant ? (If not,- then charge amount through wire cross-section within time frame is different to different observers.) Maybe it's a stupid question, but that was the point due to which I registered this question.

Comment: Current density is a component of a four-vector. But that has nothing to do with the change in the standard. The change was purely for accuracy and stability.

Comment: But since four-current depends on inverse of Lorentz factor, i.,e. $$J^{\alpha }=\rho_{u}{\gamma^{-1}}U^{\alpha }$$, then charge amount defined by (1) is also reference-frame dependent ? Also does charge conservation still applies if I can simply change my reference frame, and get different four-currents and different charge amounts ? It feels messy somehow ...

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas those are all very good questions. But they are unrelated to the change in the SI standard. I recommend asking those separately. It sounds like reading about the change in the SI inspired you to think more deeply about current and relativity

Answer (score -1):

This is Not an answer to the question, "Why?", because that can only be answered by an official of SI. Is just too long to be a comment.
I will try to give some observations and clarifications here, though.

The new standard is NOT more accurate and stable than the previous standard.
The previous standard was exact, and had been stable for many years.
The new standard is based on an experimental value, with a corresponding experimental error, that
can (and will) change from year to year.

The 2019 SI brochure states that
`An exact expression for the unit ampere in terms of the defining constant $e$ is $1 A=e/1.602176634\times 10^{-19}$''. SI calls $e$ the` elementary charge''
because it is not determined by the actual charge of any physical quantity.
$e$ is related to experiment by its appearance in the fine structure constant, which is defined  in SI units by
$\alpha=\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0{\hbar}c}$=?.  The minus sign is there because there are many different experimental numbers for the value of $\alpha$.

Since $e$, $4\pi$, $\hbar$, $c$, are already defined in SI units, the definition of $\epsilon_0$ has been changed from an exact conversion constant to an experimental number, with experimental error.
This also changes $\mu_0=1/\epsilon_0 c^2$ to now be an experimental number.
Consequently, the force per unit length between two long parallel wires, which had been
$2\times 10^{-7}II'/L$, now has the number 2 changed to
$2.00000000110(30)$.

This number is no longer exact or stable. It depends on difficult precise experiments determining alpha.
Wikipedia (Put in ``fine structure constant''.) lists 17 values for $\alpha$ measured over the past 50 years.
SI now uses the 2020 (CODATA) value, but there have already been two more accurate values since then.

That means there are now three competing values for almost any number used in SI electromagnetism.
The three values for alpha differ beyond the experimental errors, but that is not uncommon for the difficult statistics in such accurate measurements.  They cannot be averaged because of the different way each result calculates its value.

Of course, this level of accuracy and error does not bother people like you and me who use amperes mainly to buy lightbulbs, but it is an interesting observation.

Comment: $e$ is only defined by the fine structure constant if you choose it to be. But that's not the choice the SI made.

Comment: What choice did SI make?

Comment: ``An exact expression for the unit ampere in terms of the defining constant 
 is 1=/1.602176634×10−19
'' $e$ is the defining constant. It's not defined by something else.

Comment: That quote is in my answer. Their full statement is that $e$ is defined in terms of A, and A is defined in terms of $e$. That's why I mentioned the lawyer. Read on somewhere to see how $\epsilon_0$ is defined (or in my answer).  Are you saying $e$  is not a number?

Comment: It's a defined number, just like $c$ is.

Comment: In a sense, you are right.  SI has defined $e$ as a fixed defined number. But to do so, it has had to redefine $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$ as experimental results, because of the equation I wrote for $\alpha$.  $e$ was an experimental number before 2019.

Comment: Indeed that's what they did. Choosing which constants are defined, which are derived, and which are to be measured is part of the game.

Comment: This game has changed almost every number in EM.

Comment: Every instrument I've designed using them still works, and I haven't had to retract a single publication.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151760/discussion-between-jerrold-franklin-and-john-doty).

Comment: Hmm, the charge on a proton or an electron is not “the actual charge of any physical quantity”

Comment: I think I wrote, " it is not determined by the actual charge of any physical quantity."  By that I meant that, before 2019, it was determined from experiments  measuring many different things. Now it is defined in terms of the Ampere, with no experimental input.  Of course, it is the charge on many particles.

Comment: I'm afraid my 'answer' led to some confusion. I have composed a preprint that may help: https://doi.org/10.13140/RG.2.2.22419.04644